# How many realsense can be connected in one pc?

Tags: sdk, windows-10, realsense

Is it possible to connect 8 realsense in one PC without interference? 
Anything need for it??
I want to use them with sdk for unity project(win10).
If it is possible, please notice the product and sdk.

thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Check:

- [Multi-camera synchronization, IR interference, and USB bandwidth questions](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/138)
- [Are multiple cameras supported yet?](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/realsense/topic/606970)

Both give as a starting point to use the R200 camera's and librealsense. In order to have a good USB3.0 throughput and minimum frame loss, you would need a very good USB3.0 controller card. This card should be a good starting point. [Startech PEXUSB3S4V](https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/USB-3.0/Cards/4-Port-PCI-Express-PCIe-SuperSpeed-USB-3-Controller-Card~PEXUSB3S4V), buy two of them and insert them in a PCIe 2.0 slot in your pc.

Then it's probably needed/wise to program 8 separate threads, so each Realsense gets it's own thread. So for processing power you would like to have something like a 6 core processor, able to handle up to 12 threads.

Keep in mind I haven't tested this. But if you want to build such a system, I would start in this way.